# Visual Studio 2017 unable to locate javascript nuget package files

Tags: knockout.js, nuget, visual-studio-2017, nuget-package

I've recently installed visual studio 2017 and the problem i'm having is that i am unable to find .js files that are added through nuget packages.

E.g. after adding knockout.js nuget package it shows up in dependencies but the .js file doesn't appear in the solution folder or anywhere. When i add the same nuget package in vs2015 it automatically adds itself to the "Scripts" folder and i can reference it from there.

Comment: What is the detail version of your Visual Studio and what is your project type? I installed the `knockout.js` nuget package on the web application on Visual Studio 2017 15.4.1, it works fine.

Comment: I'm using the latest visual studio 2017 build as of time of writing. After i install the nuget package for knockout there's no .js file being created in the project. Can you tell me the location of where it should be placed after installing the package?

Comment: Is your project type. Net core? If yes, you should manage packages with Bower. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bower. BTW, there is discussion about "Consider deprecating Bower", you can refer to for more detail info:https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/2298

Comment: I'm having this issue too with VS2019, but only with knockoutjs. .Net Core Web project, knockout js 3.5.0 written to my .csproj file, shows installed in nuget manager... yet no js files anywhere. Furthermore, I don't have "Manage Bower" in any of the places mentioned in the article that @LeoLiu-MSFT referenced. Tried installing through the visual and command line of npm.